# Background Image shows up on Live-server, does not show up on Github Pages

Tags: css, github, github-pages

my background image works perfect on live-server but on Github pages it does not display. I read that Github pages is case sensative and you need to change `.jpg` to `.JPG`. After doing this it made all my other images work except for this background image. Here is the line of code

```
.main-image {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) ), url("../images/st-george.JPG");
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 97rem;
}
```

I have also tried:

```
 url("/images/st-george.JPG")//Without the two dots before images "../images"
```

Again this works in live-server but not on Github pages.

When I try

```
 url("./images/st-george.JPG")//One dot instead of two
```

It does not work in live-server or on Github pages.

EDIT: link to my gitgub pages :
https://calebm5577.github.io/Orthodox-Church-Website/index.html
Link to github code:
https://github.com/Calebm5577/Orthodox-Church-Website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your [css stylesheet](https://calebm5577.github.io/Orthodox-Church-Website/css/style.css) located in `css/style.css` it reads :

```
.main-image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url("./images/st-george.JPG");
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 97rem; }
```

which matches with [the code on your repository](https://github.com/Calebm5577/Orthodox-Church-Website/blob/6a10493d3419f358b61f1dec4a5541dcbb7bb433/css/style.css#L343-L349)

So it tries to get the image from `css/images/st-george.JPG` which doesn't exist

If you change it to the following it will work :

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(../images/st-george.jpg)
```

Your filename is `st-george.jpg`, *not* `st-george.JPG`

Comment: I switched it to that and it is still the same. On my project I switched the files name to .JPG and thats why it was .JPG to begin with. I just switched the text to how you put it without switching the file back, still no background picture on the website. Not sure if you can see one maybe?

Comment: @JSheckle your forgot the 2 dots : `../images/st-george.jpg`

Comment: there is currently two dots on the github. It is written ```../images/st-george.jpg```

Comment: @JSheckle Sorry my mistake but when I look at : https://calebm5577.github.io/Orthodox-Church-Website/css/style.css it shows "../images/st-george.JPG" not "../images/st-george.jpg"

Comment: I updated my github so it is capitalized again ```../images/st-george.JPG```. https://github.com/Calebm5577/Orthodox-Church-Website/blob/master/sass/pages/_home.scss

Comment: Still is not working though here. https://calebm5577.github.io/Orthodox-Church-Website/

Comment: @JSheckle still the old version : https://github.com/Calebm5577/Orthodox-Church-Website/blob/master/css/style.css#L343-L349

Comment: Perfect video! As it turns out my compile:sass was not running when I was changing things and my github repository was not changing either so I just manually changed it on both sass and css on Github. Thank you!

Comment: @JSheckle you're welcome, you can accept the answer it it's ok